# Vuex getter produces white page

Tags: vue.js, vuex, getter

I've recently started playing with Vue.js, and oh boy it is gorgeous.
But at the moment I'm facing a weird problem. I've made my template site using Vue, Vue-router and Vuex setted it up a little to look well and went to do some logic.
Suddenly I go back to look how the changes work, but I see just a white background and nothing else.
I've tracked the problem to be with Vuex. Specifically with Getters.
Whenever I try to define a Getter inside Vuex store I get white background and nothing else.
I though the problem might be old syntax or something, but it wasn't. Any getter simply broken the site.
Here is my code

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import firebase from 'firebase'

Vue.use(Vuex)

export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    user: null    

  },

  getters: {
    user: state => state.user
    },

  mutations: {

    setUser (state, payload){
      state.user = payload
    },

    
  },
  actions: {

    // TODO: REGISTRATION
    signUserUp ({commit}, payload) {
      commit('setLoading', true)
      commit('clearError')
      firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(payload.email, payload.password)
      .then(
        user => {
          commit('setLoading', false)
          const newUser = {
            id: user.uid,
            name: user.displayName,
            email: user.email,
          }
          commit('setUser', newUser)
        }
      ) .catch(
        error => {
          commit('setLoading', false)
          commit('setError', error)
          console.log(error)
        }
      )
    }, // ! END OF SIGN UP CODE

    // ! USER SIGN IN !
    signUserIn ({commit}, payload) {
      commit('setLoading', true)
      commit('clearError')
      firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(payload.email, payload.password)
      .then(
        user => {
          commit('setLoading', false)
          const newUser = {
            id: user.uid,
            name: user.displayName,
            email: user.email 
          }
          commit('setUser', newUser)
        }
      ) .catch(
        error => {
          commit('setLoading', false)
          commit('setError', error)
          console.log(error)
        }
      )
    }, // ! END OF SIGN IN CODE

    //! LOGOUT CODE
    logout({commit}) {
      firebase.auth().signOut()
      commit('setUser', null)
    },
    //! END OF LOGOUT CODE

    //! AUTO SIGNIN CODE

    autoSignIn({commit}, payload) {
      commit('setUser', {
        id: payload.id,
        name: payload.name,
        email: payload.email
      })
    }

  },
})
```

I've even tried using the getter inside the Vue.app to see if it truly is just problem with getters or if I just forgot something and there is no error response but it failed too.
Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you got any error in the console when you try to add this getter?

Comment: I got this ```[vuex] getters should be function but "getters.loading" in module "shared" is false```. It's from different getter but the error is the same

Answer (score 0):

You say this is a getter problem, but I use getters all the time and they do work.
An unused getter should just get ignored.

I don't see syntax issues in your code. That doesn't rule that out, but it does make it less likely.

So I wonder if you've checked for errors in your console, or anything like that?

Comment: I totally forgot to check that to be humble! Console produces this ```[vuex] getters should be function but "getters.user" in module "user" is false```. I tried to find where its set, but I cant

Comment: sounds like you're using a vuex-module somewhere (though I don't see it in this code). Getters in combination with modules do have a more complicated syntax.

Comment: Also: did you try setting the default user to something other than null? And do use console.log in your getter to figure out whether it sees state.user, for instance.